# Mysql Query performance -

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, sql-execution-plan, query-performance

I have the following Mysql query

```
explain SELECT count(*) as assetCount 
          FROM MdhRawAsset m 
         where sysCreationDate > date_add(now(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
           AND sysCreationDate <= now() 
           AND itemType = 'TS';
```

Results :

```
| id | select_type | table | type |possible_keys                                                    
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | range | MdhRawAsset_on_sysCreationDate, MdhRawAsset_itemType            
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|Key                          |Key_len  | ref  | rows  | Extra       |  
MdhRawAsset_on_sysCreationDate| 8       | NULL | 53269 | Using where |
```

Questions :

1. How will I know the execution time of this query ?
2. The table `MdhRawAsset` contains 37.5 million of data, is there a better way to write this query ?

Comment: which version of mysql you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

1. The execution time of a query depends on too many issues to determine how long it will take.  The load on the server, the number of rows, etc.  The best you can do is run it in a typical load and see how long it takes.
2. You seem to have the correct indexes set up, so I do not see a better way to optimize, but someone else may know better than I do.

Comment: indeed. `Using where` tells us that it is very good execution plan and such query will be performed in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Like Alan said
2. Try count(id) instead is should be faster. It depend on the database engine but in my experience not using * is always quicker.

Comment: Subtle difference with COUNT(*) vs COUNT(id):  count(*) will include NULLs whereas count(id) will exclude them.

Comment: COUNT(*) does **not** mean that all columns in the table have to be read.  It simply means to count each row without looking at values.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the execution time depends on the table, the server, the load, and what caches at the different levels are warmed up.

w.r.t. improving the performance of that specific query, a compound index on

...
KEY itemType_sysCreationDate (itemType, sysCreationDate)
...

on the table will allow that query to be executed using *only* indexes. Can't get much better than that. note that the order *is* important.

Also, replacing the 'now()' with an explicit date string generated in the application layer will allow mysql to use it's query cache if it's seen the query before, AND the table hasn't been updated since the last execution, AND the query is still in it's cache.  Not that I advocate for MySQL's query cache. ;)

Answer (score 0):

How long is it taking currently to execute this query? You do have a lot of data.

If you cannot really improve the query, maybe you need a slightly different solution -

1. Throw more hardware at the problem - see where's the bottleneck and try to upgrade that part of your hardware
2. Use summary tables - if this is a report that is drawn often, then it might help to use datawarehousing techniques to maintain summary tables. You can either update the summary tables on the fly (when the transaction is going on) or periodically (if up-to-date info is not needed).

Note that when you put data into summary tables, its not necessary to do a full count always - for eg. every new record you add in the transaction table, just do existing_summary_count = existing_summary_count + 1 and you get the incremented value for the summary without really performing an expensive query.

Answer (score 0):

You must be thinking of the query plan thing from MS-SQL server that, if memory serves, mentions something about time. Fact is, that's a crapshoot anyway. To figure out if a query will execute as fast as reasonably possibly, you need a combination of `show index from <table>` and `explain ...`.

Your query would be fastest with an index that of `itemType` and `sysCreationDate`. That would allow counting a sequential series of index entries.